# Sugerencia en JS de IDs de HTML

Tags: javascript, html, rutas, autocompletar

Quisiera saber que extensión debo activar en Visual Studio para que, por ejemplo, al escribir una busqueda por ID en Javascript, me salgan las sugerencias de ID del documento HTML.

O sea, cuando escriba document.getElementByID('m'), me salgan las sugerencias de los IDs que empiecen con esa letra.

Gracias.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones o recomendaciones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo https://www.kite.com/ por medio de machine learning el va aprendiendo de tu codigo y dandote mas sugerencia.

Solo debes descargarlo e instalarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]